# Installing Windows 8 alongside with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, windows-7, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu a long time ago from Windows 7 with Wubi. I want to give Windows 8 a try but at the same time I don't want to screw up the setup I have, and I still want to keep Windows 7. So my question is, will there be a problem if I install Windows 8?

Comment: I don't recommend Wubi. A 'real' install without Wubi works much faster.

Answer (score 0):

There would be no problem if you install windows 8 on another partition, but there will be a problem when you format the Windows 7 partition and install Windows 8, you will no longer be able to boot Ubuntu because you have installed Ubuntu using the Wubi installer.

Comment: Hi K.K Patel, thank you for your answer!, after I install windows 8 , will I be able to see windows 8 on the boot menu by default?

Answer (score 0):

First : after you install windows 8 ( in a separate partition ), it will detect windows 7 so your boot option will contain both windows .

but most probably you will loose the option to boot with Ubuntu.

You may fix this simply by,

```
try and copy 'root.disk' file from your Ubuntu installation drive using anything live boot or anything.. (this contains all your Ubuntu Data).

re install Ubuntu from Wubi. ( Into that same drive or folder)

After the installation is complete copy back the 'root.disk' file from the backup you made..
```

This should solve your issue..

Comment: Hi Vikash, Thank you for your anwser, if I re install ubuntu from wubi, will I lose any data? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Malkavian,

if you re install Ubuntu using wubi again, it will first ask you to uninstall the previous installation. so you will end up loosing your data 

That's why you need to first copy 'root.disk' file ( This is the complete ubuntu OS + your data on Ubuntu : Stored in 1 file)

Comment: It didn't work, I reinstalled the same ubuntu version, everything worked fine, but after replacing root.disk, I got this error: no such device <long random numbers> press any key.

Comment: Hi Malkavian, I am sorry about what happened, i will try and find a solution for this. but here is a link 
< wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How can I make a backup of my Wubi instal > 


It clearly mentions the same process that i told you :(

Comment: Malkavian, Are you able to log in to your windows ??

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I'm able to log into windows, in fact, I can load ubuntu from boot menu after a fresh install, but once I replace the root.disk with my root.disk I get that error

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-restore-grub-2-after-reinstalling-windows-xpvistawin7). This should help you get back grub2 without deleting any data from your ubuntu partition.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.